# Java 2d graphics performance

Tags: java, performance, opengl, graphics

If I was making a 2D game in Java, would using the default Graphics2D be fast enough? Would I get good FPS if it's just 2D? (even if there is a good amount of sprites and other things going on)
Or when your doing any kind of game programming, 2d or 3d, should you opt for opengl/directx?

Also when you render stuff with Graphics2D, is it all rendered on the CPU? Or is it hardware accelerated?

Comment: See http://game-engine-for-java.googlecode.com it uses opengl acceleration through the java2d pipeline. Gives 60-90fps with 3000 objects in the map on a pc with 512MB of ram and integrated graphics card

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use opengl/directx, or some java binding if you must use java (such as JMonkey).  If you are new to game programming, I'd suggest using the XNA framework, as it simplifies a lot of things.  I have used XNA, and it is fairly easy to use, and plug in different libraries.  If you want a browser based game, javascript + HTML5 Canvas2d, or webgl may be the best route.

You will always get better performance out of using direct binding libraries over a 2D Graphics API type library.  The main thing to do is make sure you know how images and textures are being stored / rendered, so you aren't making the framework do extra work.  Extra work will result in low FPS.